# Mac OS Leopard: SyncServer process constantly using 100% CPU

Tags: macos, mac, cpu

I am running Leopard that I upgraded from Tiger.

I've been noticing that every once in a while the SyncServer process starts up and eats up all the CPU. The fans will start going at full blast and the laptop will slow down to a crawl. I need to force quit the process from Activity Monitor to get it under control. It disappears for a while, but eventually gets started again.

I do have an iphone as well that I sync so I'm wondering if syncServer might be an apple process checking for my phone plugged in.

Edit: Tried iSync and the manual resetsync as suggested, but got this output:

$ /System/Library/Frameworks/SyncServices.framework/Versions/A/Resources/resetsync.pl full

2010-03-12 08:03:50.230 perl[176:10b] SyncServer is unavailable: exception when connecting: connection timeout: did not receive reply

PerlObjCBridge: NSException raised while sending reallyResetSyncData to NSObject object

name:     "ISyncServerUnavailableException"

reason:   "Can't connect to the sync server: NSPortTimeoutException: connection timeout: did not receive reply ((null))"
    userInfo: ""
    location: "/System/Library/Frameworks/SyncServices.framework/Versions/A/Resources/resetsync.pl line 16"
**** PerlObjCBridge: dying due to NSException

And during that syncServer started spinning up 95-100% just like it always does.

Comment: Do you use Mobile Me or iSync for syncing with any devices (beyond your iPhone)?

Comment: I don't use Mobile Me or iSync for anything other than the iphone. I'll do some backing up and try out deleting that folder. thanks for the suggestion

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try this :

Open iSync.
Choose Preferences from the iSync menu.
Click Reset Sync History.
If this does not resolve your issue, or if you are unable to open iSync, follow these steps:

In the Finder, choose Utilities from the Go menu.
Open Terminal.
In the Terminal window that opens, type or paste the following command on a single line:
/System/Library/Frameworks/SyncServices.framework/Versions/A/Resources/resetsync.pl full
Press Return.
When the operation is complete quit Terminal.

After you have reset the SyncServices folder, you may need to re-enable some Sync-related settings. Resetting SyncServices resets your Mac OS X User Account's Sync settings and any local history of updates and changes to Sync-enabled data. It won't change your current data sets, but it does delete the history of how the data arrived at its current state and disables some Sync-related settings.

[Source](http://support.apple.com/kb/TS1627)

Comment: Thanks for answering. Unfortunately neither of those options worked. See the edited question for the full error message.

Comment: You mention you upgraded from 10.4 to 10.5...If you are are getting ugly error output like that in the Console or Terminal... I might suggest doing a clean install of 10.5 after backing up your data... Drastic...but if it's barking at stuff in the Frameworks...I'd go that route....

Comment: I decided to wipe the hard drive and do a fresh install of snow leopard. Accepting this though...

Answer (score 0):

If you aren't using Mobile Me:

You can try deleting the folder `~/Library/Application Support/SyncServices` - in my experience it has fixed similar issues. It comes with a big caveat however; Apple themselves says "As if it were a swarm of bees, you should stay away from the SyncServices folder." ([Source](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT1865))

So be sure to backup your address book and calendars to be on the safe side and then go ahead and get rid of the folder.

If you're using Mobile Me:

Try unregistering all your computers in the Mobile Me System Preference and then reset your Sync Services using iSync.